# What is the EL test expression for foreign key attribute?

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl, el

I have 3 entities :

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "resultat")
    public class Resultat {

        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name="s_resultat", sequenceName="pta.s_resultat", allocationSize=1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="s_resultat")
        @Column(name = "result_code")
        private Integer code;

        @Column(name="result_intitule")
        private String lib;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "acti_code")
        private Activite activite;

        ...

    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "activite")
    public class Activite {

        @Id()
        @Column(name="acti_code")   
        private String code;

        @Column(name="acti_design")
        private String lib;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "action_code")
        private Action action;

        public Activite() {
            super();
        }

        ...

    }

@Entity
@Table(name = "action")
public class Action {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="s_action", sequenceName="pta.s_action", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="s_action")
    @Column(name = "action_code")
    private Integer code;

    @Column(name="action_design")
    private String lib;

    ...

}
```

Now I want to display a master-detail JSP page for the two entities `Activite` and `Resultat`. I created DAOs returning list of Action, list of Activite, and list of Resultat. And called them in the controller in order to be passed to the JSP.

In my JSP I loop the list of Activite first , then I loop the list of Resultat :

```
<c:forEach items="${activites}" var="activite" varStatus="statusActivite">
     <c:forEach items="${resultats}" var="resultat">
          // here I want to test if resultat is the right foreign key for the actual activite
     </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

So how to write the test for the `resultat` variable to be the foreign key associated to the `activite` ?